# why git is slow when using a high latency network

Tags: git, networking

Background information:

- Our company has a commercial 100Mb link between China and United States Office as intranet and latency is 150ms with stdev 0.2ms. 0% loss.
- The git server is located in US and developers are located in both China and US.
- When developers in US clone the repo is above 100MB/s, so the performance of the git server should not be an issue.

The developers in China who use the same command can only reach 0.5~2MB/s when the link is busy, and 3~6 MB/s during weekends or after hours.

By accident, we found if the clone is using https instead of ssh, the speed will be 11MB/s. And if set up a HTTP proxy in the US on any server or workstation and added the following to CN developers' .ssh/config, the speed of ssh clone will also be 11MB/s steady.

```
Host *
User git
ProxyCommand nc -x proxy.intranet.com 8080 -Xconnect %h %p
```

The Squid configuration is very simple,

```
acl GOOD dstdomain git.intranet.com
http_access allow GOOD
http_access deny all
http_port 8080
dns_nameservers 10.10.10.10
```

I also tried enabling the Linux BBR on a test Git server in the US but nothing is changed, I set up a squid server in China and let the git clone go through this squid server still nothing improved. It has to be a squid server located in US Intranet regardless in IDC or just a normal laptop.

I am very confused about the cause and wondering if there is a way to properly fix this issue instead of using a squid as a workaround.

*I cannot add a screenshot directly due to my reputation is low, please check the image here
[rough topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbQUc.png)

Comment: You might get better answers at https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I aimed the close recommendation at superuser but serverfault is probably better. If I were trying to debug this, I'd want to observe packets and timestamps as they enter and leave the servers in China and enter and leave the servers in the US. The obvious guess is that China is slowing down ssh (port 22) traffic for whatever national-interest reasons they might have. (They may capture all the data on disk for instance.)

Comment: (This would be easy to test: set up a secondary ssh server on another port and try that. If the traffic speed jumps up, you have something as close as you'll get to a smoking gun. They could be keying off something other than the port, though.)

Comment: just tried to add Port 222 and 12345 in sshd_config, and scp from these new ports does not bring any speed boost. if there is a throttle it's probably not port-based, could be protocol-based but not sure if there is a way to try it out.

Comment: Ok, very interesting, I used a tool called "obfs4proxy" and "proxychains" to run the ssh under Obfuscated SOCKS5, the speed has major improvement just like using Squid. I think your guess is valid, I will check with our IT guys and see anything is in our network.